# Connect DJ controller to 2x home speakers using AUX

Tags: audio

Apologies in advance if this question is stupid, but I am a complete novice when it comes to sound, so please bear with me.

Short of it is: I have  [this DJ controller](https://www.thedjshop.co.uk/pioneer-xdj-rx2-rekordbox-dj-system.html) that I normally have connected to a single speaker (Bower Wilkins A7) via an RCA-AUX cable. My question is how (if possible) I can connect the controller to 2x A7 speakers, to increase output.

Can I use a single RCA-AUX cable for each of the left and right, respectively, and connect 2x speakers of that type (BW A7)?

Alternatively, can I use the XLR connections and connect one XLR-AUX cable for each of the left/right into one A7 speaker each?

I assume some of the answers will be to buy new speakers, and that may well happen at some point, but at this moment this is the hardware I have, so I want to see what can be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a DDJ SZ by Pioneer myself, so I know the problem with different cable inputs on the speakers. If I've seen correctly on google your speakers only havea normal 3.5mm AUX cord input (correct me if I'm mistaken here).

As you want to address two of these A7 speakers you might want to address them seperately (meaning using a seperate connection for each one so you have stereo information on both speakers).

Instead of splitting one RCA into two (one for each speaker) simply use one RCA to AUX cable (which you probably already use) to connect from the controller to the first speaker and then use the same type of cable for the second speaker.

For the second speaker get some 6.3mm AUX caps for the RCA cable (something like this: https://www.amazon.de/Audio-Adapter-Klinke-Stecker-Buchse/dp/B00DPJ6LWO), so you can plug them into the booth out and connect the other side of the cable (the 3.5mm AUX part) to the speakers (as using the booth out makes only sense when playing on a stage for a bigger crowd or similar and you have monitor speakers that you can address using the booth out - and probably then the event organiser will get all the cable work done for you).

Answer (score -2):

I have done this a number of times, although I'm not a DJ myself. The best way to do this, given your situation, would be to use your XLR-AUX cables. It's affordable and it works. Also, in my experience, RCA cables (in all manifestations) have a bit less clarity than XLR.